# How to do a parallel bilinear interpolation

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I tried this but I don't know if it is right, and to calculate the time of execution sometimes it  gives me 0
in the code.

I firstly created a structure to stock all the coordinates of the point to be interpolated I have a table of points to be interpolated, so I used `pragma parallel for` to execute the *for* section to interpolate all the points. The variables R1, R2, and P are doubles, and shared among threads.

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(i=0;i<N ; i++)
  {
     R1 =  BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].x1, Table[i].Q11,Table[i].x2, Table[i].Q21,Table[i].x);
     R2 =  BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].x1, Table[i].Q12, Table[i].x2, Table[i].Q22,Table[i].x);
     P =  BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].y1,  R1, Table[i].y2,  R2, Table[i].y);
     TableInter[i] = P;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #pragma omp parallel for
 for(i=0;i<N ; i++)
 {
      R1 = BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].x1, Table[i].Q11,Table[i].x2, Table[i].Q21,Table[i].x);
      R2 = BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].x1, Table[i].Q12, Table[i].x2, Table[i].Q22,Table[i].x);
      P =  BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].y1,  R1, Table[i].y2,  R2, Table[i].y);
      TableInter[i] = P;
 }
```

The problem with your code is that `R1`, `R2`, and `P` are shared and updated by multiple threads, therefore you have a *race condition*. For example, one thread might be changing `P` while another adds `P` to the `TableInter[i]`. Nonetheless, you can easily solve this *race condition* by declaring those variables as *private*, *i.e.,* declaring them inside the parallel region, or by using the OpenMP's `private` clause (`#pragma omp parallel for private(R1, R2, P`).

```
 #pragma omp parallel for private(R1, R2)
 for(i=0;i<N ; i++)
 {
      R1 = BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].x1, Table[i].Q11,Table[i].x2, Table[i].Q21,Table[i].x);
      R2 = BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].x1, Table[i].Q12, Table[i].x2, Table[i].Q22,Table[i].x);
      TableInter[i] = BilinearInterpolation(Table[i].y1,  R1, Table[i].y2,  R2, Table[i].y);
 }
```

As long as the `BilinearInterpolation` method does not modify shared state among threads, this code is race-condition free.

> calculate the time of execution sometimes it gives me 0 in the code,

To calculate the time one can use the OpenMP function [omp_get_wtime](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu160.html), as follows:

```
double start = omp_get_wtime();
// the code that you want to measure.
double end = omp_get_wtime();  
printf("%f\n",end-start);
```